# Block all search queries except on .htaccess

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

i am currently working on a wordpress website in which I've a special case. I want one specific search query to be allowed while rejecting all others.

For example:

- `www.example.com` - PASS
- `www.example.com/page` - PASS
- `www.example.com`
- `www.example.com/?myQuery` - PASS
- `www.example.com/?anyotherQuery` - 404

Right now, I have tried it using the following re-write rule but it is also blocking access to other pages.

```
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ! myQuery
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]`
```

I'm new in rewrite and htaccess thing so need help in achieving this.

Comment: "one specific search query" - you mean one specific "query string"? And **any** URL-path?

Comment: If you're using WordPress it would make more sense to use the search within a PHP framework rather than the underlying Apache / htaccess system.

Comment: @MrWhite thats correct. Only specific query "myQuery" should be passed on all pages and all other should be 404!

Comment: @Martin, actually i have to block it through htaccess to to avoid all other bad queries.

Comment: What is your 3rd example meant to represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=myQuery
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above states... for any URL that contains a query string (first *condition*) and the query string is not exactly `myQuery` (second *condition*) then respond with a 403 Forbidden (Apache response, not WordPress).

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* makes it a lexicographical string comparison (not a regex) and the `!` prefix negates the result.

> ```
> RewriteBase "/"
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ! myQuery
> RewriteRule ^.* - [F]`
> ```

The `RewriteBase` directive is irrelevant here. The *space* between `!` and `myQuery` is erroneous. But this would potentially block anything where the query string does not *contain* `myQuery`, including when there is no query string at all.